# Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с решением следующей задачи

Tags: python

> Напишите программу, которая считывает список чисел `lst` из первой строки и число `x` из второй строки, которая выводит все позиции, на которых встречается число `x` в переданном списке `lst`.
>
> Позиции нумеруются с нуля, если число `x` не встречается в списке, вывести строку `"Отсутствует"` (без кавычек, с большой буквы).
>
> Позиции должны быть выведены в одну строку, по возрастанию абсолютного значения.

Написал такое решение:

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split(' ')]
x = int(input())
pos = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a.index(x,pos), end=' ')
    pos = a.index(x,pos) + 1
```

Программа выдает правильный ответ, однако тут же выдает:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "*путь*", line 45, in \<module\>  
>   print(a.index(x,pos), end=' ')  
> ValueError: 3 is not in list"
> ```

Нашел и другие решения задачи, но хотелось бы понять что в этом варианте не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
x = int(input()) 

indices = [pos for pos, num in enumerate(lst) if num == x]

if indices:
    for i in indices:
        print(i, end=' ')
else:
    print("Отсутствует")
```

---

*Объяснение:*

В выражении — генераторе списка (я добавил ненужные пробелы и скобки)

```
[pos        for (pos, num) in enumerate(lst)         if num == x]
```

1. Первая часть — `pos` — значит элемент, который будет добавляться в список,
2. Вторая часть — `for (pos, num) in enumerate(lst)` — значит, что будем проходить все пары (кортежи) типа (позиция_элемента, элемент) из *пронумерованного* (`enumerate`) списка `lst`.
3. Третья часть — `if num == x` — значит, что не будем добавлять элементы `pos` из *всех* парей `(pos, num)` пункта 2, но только из таких, *которые удовлетворяют условию*
   `num == x`.

Comment: Этот ответ же по сути повторяет ответ CrazyElf

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что если метод `index` не находит указанный элемент в последовательности, то выкидывается `ValueError`, вам нужно всего лишь ее отловить так:

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split(' ')]
x = int(input())
pos = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    try:
        print(a.index(x,pos), end=' ')
    except ValueError:
        break # завершаем цикл, так как дальше в списке искомого нет
    else:
        pos = a.index(x,pos) + 1
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Однако я все-ровно не могу осознать почему метод index не находит искомый элемент в списке, если он там есть. Более того, даже если в списке последний элемент (для целей последней итерации цикла) будет равен искомому, то выдается ValueError. Т.е. я не понимаю как программа и ответ дает правильный и ошибку одновременно. Или, судя из Вашего ответа, в каком именно месте когда метод index перестает находить искомый элемент

Comment: @user404236, ```index``` перестает находить элемент тогда, когда после ```pos``` его не находит, т.е. тогда, когда программа напечатала индекс последнего искомого элемента.

Comment: Спасибо, но видимо не работает у меня голова. Цикл for работает в пределе (в моем случае) len(a), т.е. после n элемента списка цикл останавливается. Если Вы правы, то мою проблему вскрыло бы если в конце списка был искомый элемент, чтобы цикл в своем конце нашел искомый элемент и не выдавал ошибку. Но даже весь список из искомых элементов никак не решает проблему

Answer (score 3):

Не устану повторять, что такие задачи лучше всего решать с помощью `списочного включения` и функции `enumerate`. Примерно так:

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split(' ')]
x = int(input())
pos_list = [i for i,el in enumerate(a) if el == x]
if pos_list:
    print(' '.join(map(str, pos_list)))
else:
    print("Отсутствует")
```

Comment: Спасибо! Обязательно научусь этим пользоваться. Новичок просто.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем нужно искать индекс, если достаточно просто обойти список?

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split(' ')]
x = int(input()) 
found = False   
for i in range(len(a)):
    if x == a[i]:
        print(i, end=' ')
        found = True 
if not found:
        print("нету")
```

Comment: Я по мелочи таки придерусь. Зачем вам `range(len())`, если есть модный `enumerate`? Зачем вам числовая переменная `count`, если вы её используете как булевый флаг по сути?

Comment: @CrazyElf А в модном enumerate в данном случае ничего полезного нет, выдаваемые им пары нам ни к чему, посконный цикл задачу лучше решает. Про count, конечно, верно

Comment: Как это ни к чему, если вы пользуетесь и элементом списка (для сравнения) и индексом (для печати) %)  Это самый что ни на есть параллельный перебор индексов и элементов списка, для чего в питон и встроен `enumerate`. А `range` и `len` тут просто лишние операции.

Comment: Булевую переменную, кстати, лучше не называть в отрицательной форме, иначе придётся ломать голову, что такое `notfound = False` ))  Переменная же `found` и конструкция `not found` понятны интуитивно.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь